# Mastheads/banners in Beamer

Tags: beamer

After a long search on the internet, I can't seem to find a solution to the following problem:

I need to created a beamer presentation. The organization that is funding me wants me to have their banner at the top of every slide. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

A very basic structure could look like shown below. The [beamer](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer) manual introduces several other themes which support a logo at the desired position. Thus a close look at that manual is suggestive.

```
\documentclass[smaller]{beamer}
\usetheme{Berkeley}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fix-cm}

\pgfdeclareimage[height=1cm]{logo}{lion-orig}
\logo{\pgfuseimage{logo}}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{The first slide}
    The »Berkeley« theme with a logo in the upper left corner.
  \end{frame}
  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{The second slide}
    The »Berkeley« theme with a logo in the upper left corner.
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The [CTAN Lion](http://ctan.org/lion.html) is an artwork by [Duane Bibby](http://duanebibby.com), courtesy of CTAN.

---

[image]